# Grid of videos, animated zoom in on one, keep structure of the rest?

Tags: css, css-transforms

I got a 4x4 grid of videos, and I have created an onclick to zoom in on a video. But when I used the animation to change the position of the clicked video, the rest of the grid changes structure.

How can I tell the other videos to stay in place, or add a placeholder div maybe? The holder div is an attempt to have a placeholder.

```
<div id=row1>
<div id=holder>
<video loop onclick="zoom(this)">
  <source src="01_Isak.m4v" type="video/mp4" />
</video>
</div>
<video loop onclick="zoom(this)">
  <source src="06_Wanda.m4v" type="video/mp4" />
</video>
<video loop onclick="zoom(this)">
  <source src="08_Anneli.m4v" type="video/mp4" />
</video>
<video loop onclick="zoom(this)">
  <source src="17_Annelie.m4v" type="video/mp4" />
</video>

</div>
<div id=row2>

<video loop onclick="zoom(this)">
  <source src="09_Caroline.m4v" type="video/mp4" />
</video>
<video loop onclick="zoom(this)">
  <source src="13_Hanna.m4v" type="video/mp4" />
</video>
<video loop onclick="zoom(this)">
  <source src="12_Åsa.m4v" type="video/mp4" />
</video>
<video loop onclick="zoom(this)">
  <source src="16_Elin.m4v" type="video/mp4" />
</video>

</div>

<script>
function zoom(e) {
        e.classList.toggle('zoom');
}
</script>
```

And the CSS.

```
@keyframes zoomie {
  0%   { }
  100% {
    z-index: 90;
    width: 75%;
    position: fixed;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  }
}

.zoom {
  -webkit-animation: zoomie 1s forwards;/* Safari 4+ */
  -moz-animation:    zoomie 1s forwards; /* Fx 5+ */
  -o-animation:      zoomie 1s forwards; /* Opera 12+ */
  animation:         zoomie 1s forwards; /* IE 10+, Fx 29+ */
}
```

Comment: First: welcome to Stack Overflow! Second, and slightly more importantly with regards to your problem: in order to help you with the problem you describe you have to show us enough of your code (think "*[mcve]*", and please read the advice there) to let us reproduce the problem you describe. How, for example, are you positioning the elements in a grid? Floats, flex-box, CSS Grid..?

Comment: Ah sorry about that. Here is a JSFiddle with my problem. https://jsfiddle.net/4o07gm3z/6/

So with this example, if I click on B then I want C D to keep the place.

Comment: If you're changing the `position` state your can't do this. Remove that and it will work. Also in your fiddle **IDs must be unique**. - https://jsfiddle.net/hz6w0b1q/

Comment: @Paulie_D, but I want the zoom to happen the way I designed it. That is the element moving to the middle of the screen with 75% width. So in my example B should move to the middle and leave an empty space between A C D.

Comment: Is this (nearly/approaching) what you're looking for: https://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/4o07gm3z/10/ (note that I've dispensed with the row wrappers, and used CSS grid for the grid layout)?

Comment: @DavidThomas Yes totally! That looks awesome. I'm gonna try it on my target environment with big videos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changed the row wrapper 's to a grid layout according to this suggestion[1](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/4o07gm3z/10)

```
body {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);
  grid-template-rows: repeat(4, min-content) 1fr;
  grid-gap: 10px;
}
.cell {
  border:1px solid #000;
  position: relative;
  background-color: rgba(255,255,255, 0.5);
}
.cell:nth-child(2n){
  grid-column: 2;
}
.cell:nth-child(3n){
  grid-column: 3;
}
.cell:nth-child(4n){
  grid-column: 4;
}
.cell:nth-child(4n) ~ .cell {
  grid-row: 2;
}
.cell:nth-child(8n) ~ .cell {
  grid-row: 3;
}
.cell:nth-child(12n) ~ .cell {
  grid-row: 4;
}
```